# IIS 7 Site using HTTPS not Accessible from Outside Internet (is accessible from intranet)

Tags: iis-7, ssl, https

I am trying to set up an HTTPS site on IIS 7. I have added the certificate, set up the appropriate bindings and the site is accesible from within my company's intranet, however no one from the outside internet can access it. I have a 1:1 NAT forward set up for port 443 that should route requests to the IP address for my server. I have the same situation for port 80 and don't have any issues with http sites being accessible.

Any suggestions for what I might be missing here?

Added info:

I am talking about the same machine that is serving HTTP successfully.

UPDATE:

As it turns out, the company that manages my company's firewall had added the exception for https and 443, and the correct routing, but hadn't added an exception for the process that handles https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the same machine serving HTTP successfully you've ruled out basic things like an improperly set default gateway. If you haven't ruled that out (because the HTTP server is a different machine) double-check that.

Are you getting a completed TCP connection to port 443 from the outside, or is it sitting stuck in SYN_SENT? An incomplete connection would make me wonder if your packets are even getting to the HTTPS server.

It's always my belief that we should look at what's on the wires to diagnose problems. You say you've got a 1:1 NAT but I'd "prove it" by looking at packets. Sniff the traffic coming into the HTTPS server and generate some requests from outside. See if they get there. Even running a `netstat -a -n` on the HTTPS server and looking for connections coming into port 443 is better than nothing.

Comment: netstat -a -n shows that the server is listening on port 443.

As far as telnet: when I try to connect I get the message "Connection is Refused"

Comment: Sounds like your connection attempt isn't getting to the server. I suppose a host based firewall could be in play, too.